# parse nested hash and iterate over to create a ruby file with output

Tags: ruby, loops, dictionary, parsing, hash

so Im trying to iterate over this nested hash to create a steps guide, I want to create a file with the information and the output file to have the output written like:

steps_guide elemento1 elemento2 elemento3

steps_guide elemento2 elemento3 elemento4

steps_guide elemento3 elemento4 elemento5

steps_guide elemento4 elemento5 elemento6

steps_guide radio xenon aluminio

steps_guide xenon aluminio boro

is there a way to make this? i tried iterating over the hash but unsuccessfully and using each_cons to iterate but still the same

Can you help me? im really stuck on this

This is my nested hash

```
_Data =[
    {
        "name": "script",
        "elements": [
            {
                "name": "unknown group",
                "headers": {
                    "map": {}
                },
                "agent": "",
                "bottom_comments": [],
                "checks": [
                    {
                        "title": "",
                        "field": "elemento1",
                        "value": "0",
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "",
                        "field": "elemento2",
                        "value": "0",
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "",
                        "field": "elemento3",
                        "value": "0",
                    },

                    {
                        "title": "",
                        "field": "elemento4",
                        "value": "0",
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "",
                        "field": "elemento5",
                        "value": "0",
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "",
                        "field": "elemento6",
                        "value": "1",
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "",
                        "field": "elemento7",
                        "value": "1",
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "",
                        "field": "elemento8",
                        "value": "1",
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "",
                        "field": "elemento9",
                        "value": "1",
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "",
                        "field": "elemento10",
                        "value": "0",

                    },
                    {
                        "type": "condiciones",
                        "elementos": [
                            {
                                
                                "table": [
                                    {
                                        "title": "",
                                        "name": "radio",
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "title": "",
                                        "name": "xenon",
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "title": "",
                                        "name": "aluminio",
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "title": "",
                                        "name": "boro",
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "title": "",
                                        "name": "oro",
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "title": "",
                                        "name": "bromo",
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "title": "",
                                        "name": "oxigeno",
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Can you be more clear - what is the exact logic you want to use to convert the hash to the file output? Just explain it with words instead of code.

Comment: I want to extract all the fields elements and put them into a created file in the format that it says, steps_guide   fields

Comment: But what part of the hash gets turned into the "steps_guide" entries? Do you put each element's "checks" into its own row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`each_cons` is the right thing to use. You're probably just having trouble because your data structure is so complicated. Part of the problem is that the last part of your table structure is its own special structure. Split them up to deal with them separately.

```
all_checks = data[0][:elements][0][:checks]
checks = all_checks[0...-1] # all but the last one

checks.each_cons(3).each do |a, b, c|
  puts "steps_guide #{a[:field]} #{b[:field]} #{c[:field]}"
end

elementos = all_checks[-1][:elementos][0][:table]
elementos.each_cons(3).each do |a, b, c|
  puts "steps_guide #{a[:name]} #{b[:name]} #{c[:name]}"
end
```

One thing that might be throwing you off is that `"title":` in a Ruby hash defines a *symbol* named `:title`, not a string as in JSON.

Comment: and for example to access to elementos and table structure to print them all?